# Expressing an Integer as the Sum of Two Fourth Powers in More than 1 way

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given the equation:

$$
x^4 + y^4 = k,
$$

where $x$, $y$ and $k$ are distinct non-zero integers, is there any $k$, such that there is more than one solution $\{x, y\}$ for the above equation?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_taxicab_number

Comment: @mathlove Thanks for that link above. I am a complete no-nothing in number theory so that would serve as a starting point.

Comment: @mathlove Following the references in the page you linked to above, it appears there is at least one solution: $$ 1584^4 + 594^4 = 1344^4 + 1334^4 = 635318657 $$ (Euler, 1772). Would you like to convert your question to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You have put a superfluous 4 as the last digit of each of your numbers, bala.

Comment: Should Be Editted. Should say "4th powers" instead of "powers of 4"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euler showed that
$$635318657 = 59^4+158^4 =133^4 + 134^4$$
is the smallest number which can be expressed as the sum of $2$ $4$th positive powers in $2$ different ways.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest number that I found can be expressed as a sum of two 4th powers in more than 1 way is:
$2602265219072= 1064^4 + 1072^4=472^4+1264^4$
Guys, guess what, I found the other way to represent 11220039255312 as a sum of two 4th powers in 2 different ways:

$11220039255312=1752^4+1158^4= 1536^4+1542^4$

I bet if anyone can find a bigger number than 11220039255312 which can be represented as a sum of two 4th powers in two different ways

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1653879)

Comment: @Unknown Well, it *does* answer the question. The question asks if there exists some $k$ which can be expressed as a sum of two 4th powers in more than 1 way.  This answer says $k=2602265219072$ works. (One of the other answers gives a link with lots of other solutions, and the solution here is bigger than all of them.)

Comment: @Unknown, please check properly, it does work and it answers the question also

Comment: I found an even bigger number , that is,11220039255312 which can be expressed as follows: 11220039255312=1536⁴ +1542⁴ But unfortunately, I cannot find the way to represent it in another way but my computer says that it can be represented in 2 ways

Comment: So, can anyone find another way to represent 11220039255312 as a sum of two positive 4th powers in another way?

Comment: @SHOUNAK You could ask this as a new question, and link back to this one.

Comment: Yeah.... it's a good idea....I might do that but did u see my second answer? It's even bigger than this one!!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a generalization of the famous [Ramanujan taxicab problem](http://www.durangobill.com/Ramanujan.html).
We are looking for integer solutions of 
$$ x^4+y^4 = z^4+w^4 $$
or:
$$ x^4-z^4 = w^4-y^4 \tag{1}$$
with $\{x,y\}\neq\{z,w\}$. [Euler found](http://euler.free.fr/taxicab4.htm):

> $$635318657 = 133^4 + 134^4 = 158^4 + 59^4\tag{2}$$

and that is the smallest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of results by Jarek Wroblewski http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~jwr/422/422-10m.txt, the first of which is the famous one by Euler already cited

Answer (score 1):

Since, nobody could find a greater number than  11220039255312 , so, I found it on my own and here it is:
$26033514998417=2189^4+1324^4=1784^4+1997^4$

Comment: This one also works, and this is the biggest solution I've found yet.