# Numbers greater than $26033514998417$ that can be expressed as a sum of two positive 4th powers in more than 1 way

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, integers

Are there any numbers greater than
$26033514998417$ which can be expressed as a sum of two positive 4th powers in atleast 2 ways ?

And if there are any such numbers, then, please include the number(s) that u have found in your answer.

In case, if anybody wants to know how the number

$26033514998417$ can be expressed as a sum of two positive 4th powers in 2 ways, here it is:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4237040/857041

Comment: context for this problem?

Comment: The conditions must be as follows: x^4+y^4=k, where x,y and k are non-zero integers , such that there is more than 1 solution{x,y} for the above equation and k>$26033514998417$

Comment: You mean, apart from multiplying the given number by 16, 81, etc?

Comment: I hope this question is clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$17472238301875630082 = 62047^4 + 40351^4 = 59693^4 + 46747^4$$ from [A018786](https://oeis.org/A018786), all primes btw.

Dunno why that list stops at 835279626752, though, presumably because a sequence must be complete, i.e. all numbers smaller and *not* in the list *must not* have the property.

---

**Addendum**:  and [here is a list](http://cr.yp.to/sortedsums/two4.1000000) with 516 primitive entries from Daniel J. Bernstein (found via [A003824](https://oeis.org/A003824)), that ends

```
...
955378 168531 883693 688026
960319  87924 942337 498984
962724 455837 870557 756684
972841 283961 967979 394717
988582 158157 976563 463702
989216 283949 958163 590024
989426 503473 938698 704399
989727 161299 913141 717447
990518   1039 967823 540326
```

---

**Addendum 2:** Here is a 146-digit solution from [PrimePuzzles 103](https://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_103.htm)

```
75326517042882955509049316560407015204559148957492168402274838923500008575948738239692316743036018051328508933923770491774189595934532956237348642
= 1679539956802461427023806692932554869^4
+ 2864939822128245005298014063613916133^4
=  735636962517662175684582548040182073^4
+ 2096549864621014042130013452441703601^4
```

They mention an identity from a [collection by Edward Brisse](http://euler.free.fr/identities.htm) on [EulerNet](http://euler.free.fr):
$$f_2^4(a,b)+f_2^4(b,-a)=f_2^4(a,-b)+f_2^4(b,a)$$
where
$$f_2(a,b)=
-a^{13}+a^{12}b+a^{11}b^2+5a^{10}b^3+6a^9b^4-12a^8b^5-4a^7b^6+7a^6b^7-3a^5b^8-3a^4b^9+4a^3b^{10}+2a^2b^{11}-ab^{12}+b^{13}$$

The collection has also (other) identidies of degree 7, 13, 19 and 31 for $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$.  And there are identities that solve $x^4+y^4+z^4=2w^4$ like

$$(a^2-b^2)^4 + (a^2 + 2ab)^4 + (2ab + b^2)^4
= 2(a^2 + ab + b^2)^4$$

So this rabbit hole seems to go infinitly deep, both in terms of formulae and in terms of solutions you can generate with each formula.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: @SHOUNAK GUPTA: I found a list with even bigger primitive entries, see "Addendum".

Comment: $962608047985759418078417 = 990518^4+1039^4=967823^4+540326^4$ has 24 digits.

Comment: Yes, u are correct....I also saw a list from D.Wilson:https://oeis.org/A003824/b003824.txt

Comment: The largest number comes from the $514^{th}$ instead of $516^{th}$ entry. It is $1022624816783516967864017 = 989426^4 +  503473^4 = 938698^4 + 704399^4$

Comment: And the paper where Daniel J.Bernstein talks about "Enumerating solutions to p(a)+q(b)=r(c)+s(d)" is here:.    Here's the link to the file:

https://in.docworkspace.com/d/sALIKc77niZk6q5yMiaqnFA

Shared from WPS Office:
https://kso.page.link/wps

Comment: @SHOUNAK GUPTA: See "Addendum 2" for bigger solutions and generic formulae to generate solutions.

Comment: Yeah...They really do go infinitely deep.... Anyways, thank you so much for spending your precious time in answering my question and a special thanks for the"Addendum 2" :)