# Diophantine equation $\frac{x^4 + y^4}{z^4 + t^4} = u^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find (many, a family of) non-trivial solutions of the diophantine equation

$$\frac{x^4 + y^4}{z^4 + t^4}= u^2\ \ (*)$$

Notes:

1. If the $\{x,y\}$, $\{z,t\}$ are proportional then we have a trivial solution. So we are interested in non-trivial solutions
2. The equation $\frac{x^4 + y^4}{z^4 + t^4}= 1$ is known as the generalized taxicab problem, see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405867/expressing-an-integer-as-the-sum-of-two-fourth-powers-in-more-than-1-way). The smallest known solutions are fairly large.
3. Perhaps one could try to solve it for some concrete $u>1$, like $u=2$.
4. Origin of the problem: I was looking for squares $a^2$, $b^2$, $c^2$, such that $a^2 + b^2$, $b^2 + c^2$, $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ are also square. Let's write

$$\begin{aligned}a &= (x t)^2 - (y z)^2 \\
  b &= 2 x y z t\\
  c&= (x z)^2 - (y t)^2\end{aligned}$$

Now $a^2 + b^2 = ((x t)^2 + (y z)^2)^2$, $b^2 + c^2 = ((x z)^2+ (y t)^2)^2$, and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = x^4 t^4 + y^4 z^4 + x^4 z^4 + y^4 t^4= (x^4 + y^4)(z^4 + t^4)$. Therefore, we need $(x^4 + y^4)(z^4 + t^4)$ to be a square. Note that we need non-proportional solutions, otherwise we get $a=0$, or $b=0$.

4. The equation can be rewritten as
   $$(x^4 + y^4)(z^4 + t^4) = v^2\ \ (**)$$
5. Per Fermat, the equation $x^4 + y^4 = w^2$ has no trivial solutions.
6. It would be nice to have a family of solutions.
7. Possible approach to finding solutions to the equation in form $(**)$. List pairs $x<y$ relatively prime and determine the square free part of $x^4 + y^4$. Then look for concidences $s(x^4 + y^4) = s(z^4 + t^4)$ ( perhaps a simplistic approach).

Any feedback would be appreciated! Thank you for your attention!

Comment: See for example [here](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/ms-2017-0305/html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a table with small solutions ($x \le y \le 7300$, ordered by $y$)
for the equation
$$x^4+y^4 = u^2(z^4+t^4);$$

it is divided into $3$ parts:

- $u=1$;
- $u=41$;
- other values for $u$.

\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
x & y & z & t & u \\
\hline 
59 & 158 & 133 & 134 & 1 \\
7 & 239 & 157 & 227 & 1 \\
193 & 292 & 256 & 257 & 1 \\
271 & 502 & 298 & 497 & 1 \\
103 & 542 & 359 & 514 & 1 \\
222 & 631 & 503 & 558 & 1 \\
76 & 1203 & 653 & 1176 & 1 \\
878 & 1381 & 997 & 1342 & 1 \\
1324 & 2189 & 1784 & 1997 & 1 \\
1042 & 2461 & 2026 & 2141 & 1 \\
248 & 2797 & 2131 & 2524 & 1 \\
1034 & 2949 & 1797 & 2854 & 1 \\
1577 & 3190 & 2345 & 2986 & 1 \\
1623 & 3494 & 2338 & 3351 & 1 \\
661 & 3537 & 2767 & 3147 & 1 \\
3364 & 4849 & 4288 & 4303 & 1 \\
2694 & 4883 & 3966 & 4397 & 1 \\
604 & 5053 & 1283 & 5048 & 1 \\
2027 & 6140 & 4840 & 5461 & 1 \\
274 & 6619 & 5093 & 5942 & 1 \\
2707 & 6730 & 3070 & 6701 & 1 \\
498 & 6761 & 5222 & 6057 & 1 \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\hline
2 & 13 & 1 & 2 & 41 \\
364 & 685 & 88 & 95 & 41 \\
1223 & 2977 & 149 & 467 & 41 \\
1417 & 5078 & 346 & 787 & 41 \\
5146 & 5803 & 169 & 1022 & 41 \\
8206 & 9633 & 894 & 1637 & 41 \\
? & ? & ? & ? & ? \\
\hline
38 & 43 & 1 & 2 & 569 \\
121 & 205 & 5 & 7 & 809 \\
159 & 269 & 9 & 13 & 409 \\
151 & 388 & 7 & 8 & 1889 \\
9 & 437 & 1 & 3 & 21089 \\
314 & 863 & 1 & 2 & 182209 \\
859 & 1186 & 1 & 2 & 385241 \\
10 & 1261 & 5 & 22 & 3281 \\
1112 & 1323 & 7 & 12 & 14089 \\
908 & 1559 & 7 & 8 & 31841 \\
1041 & 2219 & 3 & 7 & 101201 \\
2277 & 2521 & 1 & 3 & 905761 \\
1166 & 2589 & 9 & 38 & 4729 \\
2148 & 2723 & 12 & 23 & 15929 \\
1383 & 2936 & 7 & 12 & 58049 \\
1006 & 3177 & 2 & 3 & 1029961 \\
911 & 3633 & 21 & 59 & 3769 \\
475 & 3823 & 5 & 7 & 265721 \\
1951 & 5777 & 79 & 103 & 2729 \\
1897 & 5983 & 71 & 127 & 2129 \\
2962 & 6741 & 22 & 57 & 14089 \\
4969 & 6987 & 77 & 111 & 4001 \\
4719 & 7187 & 1 & 3 & 6211649 \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots 
\end{array}

I'm curious why $u=41$ is relatively rich with solutions (after $u=1$). I have doubts if there are infinitely many solutions for $u=41$.

And, of course, I see no parametrization of solutions (to have a family of them).

Comment: Thank you, that is very interesting!  So after $u=1$, it seems that the next $u$ with solutions is $41$?  The only thing I know about $41$ is that it is prime, and also that polynomial $x^2 - x + 41$. It seems there are many solutions for $u=1$ ( infinitely many?)

Comment: @orangeskid, yes, it looks like there are infinitely many solutions for $u=1$: see please Jaroslaw Wroblewski results: https://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~jwr/422/ , https://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~jwr/422/422-10m.txt , http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~jwr/422/422.zip

Comment: Oh, thank you!  That is impressive indeed.  Now, Dietrich Burde was kind  to provide this [link](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/ms-2017-0305/html). I wonder if they are able to get any solutions from elliptic curves. Maybe it could show infinity of solutions ( I don't have access to the article).

Answer (score 3):

Consider the equation,

$$x^4+y^4 = u^2(z^4+t^4)$$

then there is a solution for *infinitely* many $u$ with special properties. Let,

\begin{align}u 
&=\,4(p^4+q^4)^4-3(p^4-q^4)^4\\[6pt]
&=\frac{(p^2-q^2)^8+(2pq)^8+(p^2+q^2)^8-\tfrac32(2pq)^8}{2}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{2(p^8 + 14p^4q^4 + q^8)^2 - \tfrac32(2pq)^8}{2}
\end{align}

Note the *Pythagorean triple* $(p^2-q^2,\, 2pq,\, p^2+q^2)$ and the appearance of the polynomial $(p^8 + 14p^4q^4 + q^8)$ which is an invariant of the *octahedron*,

[image: Octahedron]

Then we have *Carmichael's identity*,

$$p^4(p^8 - 6p^4q^4 - 3q^8)^4 + q^4(3p^8 + 6p^4q^4 - q^8)^4 = (p^4 +q^4)u^2$$

more noted for his *Carmichael numbers*. For example, let $(p,q)=(1,2)$, then,

$$314^4 + 863^4 = (1^4 + 2^4)182209^2$$

which appears in the table in the first answer. Some remarks: First, while $u$ gets large very fast, it does prove there are infinitely many of them. Second, for the special case $u=1$,

$$x^4+y^4 = z^4+t^4$$

this has been discussed in several [MSE posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4255315/4781) and there are infinitely many polynomial parameterizations for $(x,y,z,t)$ by using an elliptic curve, as first done by Euler. Third, whether there are polynomial parameterizations for $u=41$ and others remains to be seen.

Comment: I am impressed with the fact that there are families of solutions.  Will have to fire up some CAS and check.  Amazing again, thank you!

Comment: Nice solution. Because of the showed non-homogenous of $36$-degree   Carmichael's identity, probably it gives ALL the solutions. Anyway, difficult to find out a solution don't having this identity as a source.

Comment: @Piquito Thanks. But no, it doesn't give all solutions. It does show that if you give me _any_ two integers $(p,q)$, then I can quickly find two integers $(r,s)$ such that $$\frac{r^4+s^4}{p^4+q^4}=\text{square}$$

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Yes I see, when $p,q$ are not coprimes.

Comment: @orangeskid I assume you like unusual connections. Turns out Carmichael's parameterization was hiding an octahedron. Dunno why though. Probably has to do with all the $4$th and $8$th powers.

Comment: Wow, again!  Will sit down soon with the formulas. Thank you!!