# On $a^4+b^4=c^4+d^4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, reference-request, diophantine-equations

A Pythagorean triple consists of three positive integers $a,b,c$ such that
$$a^2+b^2=c^2.$$
There are infinitely many solutions. On the other hand, it is known that
$$a^4+b^4=c^4$$
has no positive integer solutions.

However, I tried to modify the last equation and came up with the following question:

Are there positive integers $a,b,c,d$ such that *they are all distinct* and
$$a^4+b^4=c^4+d^4?$$
If so, does it have infinitely many solutions? Does this equation even have a name? If so, a reference would be useful.

Comment: Yes, just put $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: @SergeiNikolaev Check the edited post.

Comment: Did you try to write a program (Python, c, etc.) to check if any $a,b,c,d$ from $[1, 1000]$  fit the equation?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts or working to start us off with?

Comment: Leo. Euler said $59^4 + 158^4 = 133^4 + 134^4$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expressing an Integer as the Sum of Two Fourth Powers in More than 1 way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405867/expressing-an-integer-as-the-sum-of-two-fourth-powers-in-more-than-1-way) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5E4%2Bb%5E4%3Dc%5E4%2Bd%5E4%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Adistinct%20positive%20integers&p=1). FYI, there's also somewhat related AoPS thread of [Somehow hard](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1300855p6928981), but with the sum being equal to a fifth power.

Comment: @Hanno FYI, this [answer](/a/1405883) of the proposed duplicate mentions that same result from Euler. Also, the other answers there generally give, either explicitly and/or with a link, additional results.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Do you know if there are infinitely many such numbers?

Comment: @japjap Based on only requiring the integers to be positive & distinct, there are infinitely many such numbers. Just take any solution, such as Euler's solution of $59^4+158^4=133^4+134^4$ (mentioned in Hanno's comment & mathlove's duplicate question answer), then multiply both sides by $k^4$ for any integer $k\gt 1$ to get $(59k)^4+(158k)^4=(133k)^4+(134k)^4$. However, apart from such relatively trivial results, i.e., with the additional condition of $\gcd(a,b,c,d)=1$, unfortunately I don't know much about it, including things like whether or not there are infinitely many such numbers.

Comment: Leo. Euler's instance (being minimal) is the generalised Taxicab number $T(4,2,2)$.
There are more instances, also @JohnOmielan , cf  
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation4thPowers.html
 starting at $(115)$.

Comment: Still another one, quite large & not listed on the wolfraMathworld page
$$4608535738441446497 = 1918^4 + 46333^4 = 35651^4 + 41594^4$$